# 503 error when downloading wikipedia dumps

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have the following script to download (and later on process) Wikipedia's pageviews dumps. I am getting 503 errors on all the pages (whose urls are correct).

```
import argparse
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import async_timeout
import re

base_url = "http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/{year}/{year}-{month:02d}/pagecounts-{year}{month:02d}{day:02d}-{hour:02d}0000.gz"

async def downloadFile(semaphore, session, url):
    try:
        async with semaphore:
            with async_timeout.timeout(10):
                async with session.get(url) as remotefile:
                    if remotefile.status == 200:
                        data = await remotefile.read()
                        outfile = re.sub("/", "_", url[7:])
                        with open(outfile, 'wb') as fp:
                            print('Saving')
                            fp.write(data)
                    else:
                        print(remotefile.status)
                        return
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return

async def aux(urls):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            print(url)
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(downloadFile(sem, session, url))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--year", type=int, default=2016)
    parser.add_argument("--month", type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument("--temp_folder", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    urls = []

    for day in range(1, 32)[:3]:
        for hour in range(24)[:2]:
            urls.append(base_url.format(
                year=args.year, month=args.month, day=day, hour=hour))

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(aux(urls))
    loop.run_until_complete(aux(urls))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
<ClientResponse(https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/2016/2016-04/pagecounts-20160402-000000.gz) [503 Service Temporarily Unavailable]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Server': 'nginx/1.13.6', 'Date': 'Wed, 24 Oct 2018 21:27:58 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '213', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=106384710; includeSubDomains; preload')>
```

But this is really weird as copy-pasting the same urls on my chrome browser does the job!

Comment: How many requests are you making per second? I don;t see anything in this script in terms of `time.sleep` and `service temporarily unavailable` generally means you are either sending too many requests to process, or (more likely) you are being rate limited to prevent spamming/DOSing

Comment: 5xx normally should mean that there's something wrong with the server. 4xx codes indicate that the client did something wrong. **429 Too Many Requests** would be the proper status code to signal that your crawler should calm down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played with code and I can say following:

- Wikipedia doesn't allow multiple requests per IP
- Timeout 10 for this url is too low

To make your code work:

- Change `asyncio.Semaphore(10)` to `asyncio.Semaphore(1)`
- Change `async_timeout.timeout(10)` to `async_timeout.timeout(120)`
- Completely remove line `asyncio.ensure_future(aux(urls))`, you don't need it since you pass you pass `aux(urls)` to `run_until_complete`

Final version that successfully downloads single archive:

```
import argparse
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import async_timeout
import re

base_url = "http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/{year}/{year}-{month:02d}/pagecounts-{year}{month:02d}{day:02d}-{hour:02d}0000.gz"

async def downloadFile(semaphore, session, url):
    try:
        async with semaphore:
            with async_timeout.timeout(120):
                async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as remotefile:
                    if remotefile.status == 200:
                        data = await remotefile.read()
                        outfile = re.sub("/", "_", url[7:])
                        with open(outfile, 'wb') as fp:
                            print('Saving')
                            fp.write(data)
                    else:
                        print('status:', remotefile.status)
                        return
    except Exception as e:
        print('exception:', type(e), str(e))
        return

async def aux(urls):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1)
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            print('url:', url)
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(downloadFile(sem, session, url))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--year", type=int, default=2016)
    parser.add_argument("--month", type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument("--temp_folder", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    urls = []

    for day in range(1, 32)[:1]:
        for hour in range(24)[:1]:
            urls.append(base_url.format(
                year=args.year, month=args.month, day=day, hour=hour))

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(aux(urls))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Nice work. I guess with semaphore only allowing one connection, the code could be made even simpler. The semaphore itself is redundant, as is assembling the list of tasks and `gather`. Each step of the loop could just `await downloadFile(...)`.